# Trimming double quotes of a string which is saved as a value in mongodb java driver

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have something like this written using mongodb driver for java:

```
doc = new BasicDBObject("Physicalentity", "Pressure").
append("Sensor", "Tinkerforge").
append("Unit", "Lux").  
append("loc", Location).
append("value", pressure).
append("time", time).
append("date", date);


pre_collection.insert(doc);
```

As you can see in the above code, I do not insert double quote for attribute `loc` and the location is defined as follow:

```
String longtitude = "8.9043";
String latitude = "52.0777";
String Location = "["+longtitude+","+latitude+"]";
```

Now In the database it is stored as:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5367da1211f6e33b6eba4a9f"} , "Physicalentity" : "Pressure" , "Sensor" : "Tinkerforge" , "Unit" : "Lux" , "loc" : "[8.9043,52.0777]" , "value" : "Air Pressure: 1008.177 mbar" , "time" : "20.36.02" , "date" : "05.05.2014"}
```

but as you can see the attribute loc is stored with double quotes `"[8.9043,52.0777]"` but I want them to be saved without the double quotes or if possible like this: `“loc:[51,-114]”`

I would really appreciate a help here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want the `Location` (why is this capitalized?) to be written as if it were a `double[]` instead of a `String`. Have you tried changing it to a `double[]`?

Answer (score 1):

When writing that value, use a BasicDBList for your two coordinates.  This will cause them to be saved out as an array in your document.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/):

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("Physicalentity", "Pressure").
append("Sensor", "Tinkerforge").
append("Unit", "Lux").  
append("loc", new BasicDBObject("longtitude", 203).append("latitude", 102));
append("value", pressure).
append("time", time).
append("date", date);
pre_collection.insert(doc);
```

But maybe you can do a little trick and remove with code the first and the last quotes like this:

```
String word="[wdsd34svdf]";
System.out.println(word.substring(1, word.length()-1));
```

I hope it helps :)